# Attached a pop up to a cursor, now buttons aren't working on UI in Flash CS6

Tags: cursor, flash-cs6

I have a small pop up balloon that I coded to look like it's coming off of the cursor. It moves along with the cursor and looks fine.

The problem I have run into, though, is that the buttons I have created no longer work when the cursor is over them. When the balloon pop up is **not** attached to the cursor, the buttons work fine...the Hover state for the button appears as it should and the cursor turns into the hand/pointed finger icon. When I attached the cursor bubble, however, nothing seems to work with the button.

Here is what I have for code:

```
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,follow);

    function follow(E:MouseEvent){

    cursorbubble.x = mouseX;

    cursorbubble.y = mouseY;

    }
```

What do I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure if this was all that mattered, but it looks like the pop up bubble attached to the cursor was getting in the way of the stage recognizing the cursor was within/over a button. I offset the pop up bubble by about 20 px and now everything works as expected.